# Mysql SUM function returns returns wrong decimal values

Tags: mysql, sum

I have the following table with the test data set:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `desc` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    insert into `test` (`id`, `desc`, `amount`) values('5',NULL,'847.3');
    insert into `test` (`id`, `desc`, `amount`) values('6',NULL,'-847');
    insert into `test` (`id`, `desc`, `amount`) values('7',NULL,'847.3');
    insert into `test` (`id`, `desc`, `amount`) values('8',NULL,'-847');
    insert into `test` (`id`, `desc`, `amount`) values('9',NULL,'847.4');
```

So the table looks like:

[image]

Now my problem is that when I use:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM test;
```

I get the following results `847.9999999999999` instead of the expected `848`.

Any ideas why I dont get the decimals rounded?

Update:

I am have tested this on `MySQL Server: 5.5.17` (windows) and `MySQL Server: 5.5.20` Centos

Comment: Use the `decimal` type rather than `double` which is floating point and so carries an inherent imprecision; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831217/double-vs-decimal-in-mysql

Comment: i would suggest you to use a DECIMAL type, instead of a DOUBLE

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc2bf/1 . 848 as result.

Comment: Try using `round()`..

Comment: as you can see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc2bf/1 your query and the result is fine.

Comment: i prefer a base 7 numbering system just to throw off the hackers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem inherent to the way [floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) are represented by a computer. Basically, some values in base 10, which can be written with a finite number of digits, cannot be represented in base 2.

Most of the time, such approximations go unnoticed, because you only display a small number of decimal digits. But when you start adding and multiplying these approximate values, the error accumulates up to a point where it becomes noticeable.

This is why the [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html) type exists. It essentially represents a decimal value as an integer, divided or multiplied by a power of 10. With such a representation, no approximation is ever made.