# Java netbeans adding comma to the table

Tags: java, mysql

Hi i am new to this and i am locked in this problem, i am trying to figure out whether you can add a set of values `(1,000 ....)` to another value. Though i successfully linked an input that automatically changed into comma to the table in `SQL`, it seems that it cannot add two values that has that format, my client wants to see a comma in a table and when inputting values.

Can you guide me where to change my code, is there an automatic format of these in `SQL`? Or probably in the `java` code, I read some articles that you cannot do a comma format before adding as it is done after that.

Here is the code I added to automatically change the numbers into having a comma:

```
private void FaremoKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
{
    String a = Faremo.getText();

    if (a.isEmpty())
    {
        a = "";
    }
    else
    {
        a = a.replace(",","");
        a =  NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(Double.parseDouble(a));
        a = a.replace(".", ",");
    }
    Faremo.setText(a);
}
```

My problem is i cannot add values linked to my `SQL` with that format.
[Sample data - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVQII.png]

When i am getting the sum of it I am using these:

```
   private void SumActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
  try{
    String sql = "Select sum(Faremo),sum(Eatery),sum(Admin),sum(Jisoo),sum(Cav1),sum(Cav2),sum(Reliance1),sum(Reliance2)from Dataa";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
        String sum1 = rs.getString("sum(Faremo)");
        SFaremo.setText(sum1);

        String sum2 = rs.getString("sum(Eatery)");
        SEatery.setText(sum2);

        String sum3 = rs.getString("sum(Admin)");
        SAdmin.setText(sum3);

        String sum4 = rs.getString("sum(Jisoo)");
        SJisoo.setText(sum4);

        String sum5 = rs.getString("sum(Cav1)");
        SCav1.setText(sum5);

        String sum6 = rs.getString("sum(Cav2)");
        SCav2.setText(sum6);

        String sum7 = rs.getString("sum(Reliance1)");
        SReliance1.setText(sum7);

        String sum8 = rs.getString("sum(Reliance2)");
        SReliance2.setText(sum8);

    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
Update_table();

}
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you fix your code without being able to actually see it. Could you share it, and highlight where exactly your problem is?

Comment: I hope i added the right one

Answer (score 0):

Are the table columns where you want to save the numbers defined as float?

Comment: I used TEXT and VARCHAR

Comment: So you can't add a formated number like 1,000 to your table as a new column?

Comment: no, i can add it just fine, the problem is when performing operation such as SUM of all values in it

Comment: Okey but why do you save it with a comma then in the database ? Wouldn't it be better to save it as normal number and format it when you select it ?

Comment: hmm i am just linking my database to display it in the table in the netbeans so i guess adding with comma is not possible, but also i want to display a comma in my table, i might look up for a solution to these.Thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that a value will only be a number make the table columns `int`. Depending on the kind of numbers, you can choose a variety of `Data Types`:
[float](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html), [decimal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html),[real](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_real_as_float).
These could all work. It is all depending on what the numbers represent.

If you are going to do math IN the cells, a `double` gives rounding problems ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831217/double-vs-decimal-in-mysql)). 
For more info on `Data Types` check [Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-overview.html).

Comment: hmm, i get it and will follow your guide but not an answer i was looking for

Comment: Also possible is when doing a `SUM` of all values, `parse` the text/varchar (if they are all numbers) to a `float`, then do the SUM, and then `parse` them to `String` again. Just make sure to add the right amount of decimals.