# Wrong output in MYSQL update when multiple value by column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am using following query in **MYSQL** to multiply value in colname by **1000**. data type of colname is **double**.It works fine but for one value in table it is giving wrong output. value is **1066203.9** and after update value should be **1066203900** but output is **1066203899.9999999**.

```
UPDATE tablename SET colname=colname*1000 WHERE id=1
```

Comment: check datatype of your column.Might be out of range value.

Comment: doubles are not precise, so what you see can be normal... see this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831217/double-vs-decimal-in-mysql you might want to use decimal instead

Comment: Perhaps the value you see before multiplying, 1066203.9, is actually rounded from1066203.89999999999

Comment: When I use 1066203.8 instead of 1066203.9 means .8 instead of .9 then it works fine

Comment: @fthiella will it affect existing values if I change datatype from double to decimal

Comment: @ PeteH value is 1066203.90 when I read it and inserted in database it stored as 1066203.9

Comment: yes, if you change the datatype from double to decimal there could be some rounding issues also...

Comment: @fthiella  I tried with decimal(10,2) but ouput is 99999999.99.

Comment: `decimal(10,2)` means 10 digits, 2 of these after the decimal point (and thus 8 before it), so `99999999.99` is your maximal value. Just use more digits if you need more digits.