# storing value from variable in if else statement to database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is a progression from last night's question, now I need to get the value from `$total` in my if/else statement and insert it into my database. `$count['NumRows']` for price and `$total` for total_all...
I've read about changing the value to array by using `implode`, but the problem is still there, my database still won't store the value... because I don't know why and I need help...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $names      = $_POST['names'];
    $phones     = $_POST['telno'];
    $modelname  = $_POST['modelname'];
    $rentaldate = $_POST['rentaldate'];
    $numday     = $_POST['numday'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO carbook (name, tel_no, model_name, rental_date, return_date, no_of_days) VALUES ('$names', '$phones', '$modelname', '$rentaldate', '$returndate', '$numday')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) == true) {
        echo "Name: $names";
        echo "<br/>Phones: $phones";
        echo "<br/>Car Name: $modelname";
        echo "<br/>Rental Date: $rentaldate";
        echo "<br/>Return Date: $returndate";
        echo "<br/>No Of Days: $numday";
        echo "<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: $sql<br>$conn->error";
    }

    if ($modelname && $numday) {

        if ($modelname = 'Jetta') {

            $countrows = 'SELECT price_day AS NumRows FROM carlist WHERE carBookId = 1';
            $result    = $conn->query($countrows);
            $count     = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $total     = $count['NumRows'] * $numday;

            $total = number_format($total, 2);

            echo 'Price per day: RM<b>' . $count['NumRows'] . '</b>.<br/>';
            echo 'Total Price: RM<b>' . $total . '</b>.';

            $sql = "INSERT INTO carbook (price, total_all) VALUES ('$total', '$countrows')";
```

There's no error, but the database didn't recognize the value, and it still inserts 0 in my table.

edited this is my table structure
[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NczVV.png)

Comment: Is this query supposed to be countin rows where `carBookId` is one? `SELECT price_day AS NumRows FROM carlist WHERE carBookId = 1'`

Comment: Firstly try changing `if ($modelname = 'Jetta') {` to `if ($modelname == 'Jetta') {` I think you want to compare `$modelname` to `'Jetta'` not set `$modelname`'s value.

Comment: is this a typo `$numday=$_POST["numday"];
    ;`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly that is suppose to fetch the price in the database table

Comment: Then the query is very misleading. When you copy stuff, make it make sense in its new situation. `SELECT price_day AS NumRows` makes it look like you are trying the get a row count and not just get a price

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i admit i copy some of that while learning all through it.. and so i am open to suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

You are paasing wrong variables in insert query

```
$numRows = $count['NumRows'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO carbook (price, total_all)
                            VALUES ('$numRows','$total' )";
```

**EDIT**

From your table structure I can see there may be 2 issues :

**1)** In your table there are other fields also which doesn't have default values as well as there must not be null So also append those fields in insert query.

**2)** Do not enclose value in single quotes for int or double data types

Comment: i use the coding u gave,no error and i think its good but its still giving 0 in my database... is it posible for table in my database to affect my coding?

Comment: show your table structure. Also you are getting result in `echo 'Price per day: RM<b>'. $count['NumRows'] . '</b>.<br/>';          
            echo 'Total Price: RM<b>'. $total . '</b>.';` ?

Comment: i have uploaded my table structure, yes the result are shown, no error so far, just the database still fecthing 0

Comment: i have a hard time following your 1st suggestion...can u explain it on more understandable term for me
and how to append those fields in insert query. the result still coming out 0...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert the string (query) in the variable $countrows into your total_all field. Your datatype in your database is probably interpreting this string incorrectly and inserting a 0.
You need to replace the the $countrows with the alias you have created in the query.

```
$numberOfRows = $count['NumRows'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO carbook (price, total_all) VALUES ('$numberOfRows', '$total')";
```

**EDIT:** This worked for me

```
$numberOfRows = $count['NumRows'];
$total     = $numberOfRows * 3;
$totalFormatted = number_format($total, 2);

echo 'Price per day: RM<b>' . $numberOfRows . '</b>.<br/>';
echo 'Total Price: RM<b>' . $totalFormatted . '</b>.';
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO carbook (price, total_all) VALUES ('$total', '$numberOfRows')");
```

Comment: You said in your title you wanted this $count['NumRows'] for price and $total for total_all but in your code you have done this. Are you sure you have them in the right order INSERT INTO carbook (price, total_all)
                            VALUES ('$total','$countrows' )" does it need to be thisINSERT INTO carbook (price, total_all)
                            VALUES ('$countrows','$total' )"

Comment: yep ive been wondering about that, because i make the query inside the if statement... i dont know whether its working or not because no error shown here 
$sql = "INSERT INTO carbook (price, total_all)
           VALUES ('$numRows','$total' )";

Comment: So firstly do the echos above the INSERT output the correct values? If they are correctly outputting it then the values are not the problem. What are the datatypes on each column in the Database?

Comment: i edited and already uploaded the table structure aboved, tell me anything u found weird ok...

Comment: Seems OK but read this when you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831217/double-vs-decimal-in-mysql. Can you let me know what the output of the two echo statements above your INSERT are please? The  echo 'Price per day: RM<b>' . $count['NumRows'] . '</b>.<br/>'; AND  echo 'Total Price: RM<b>' . $total . '</b>.';

Comment: Also have you switched your VALUES around as they are in the wrong order so my answer above but change to this ($total, '$numberOfRows')

Comment: Price per day: RM13300.
Total Price: RM39,900.00.
price per day for $numRows and total price for $total

Comment: Ok firstly you are trying to insert a number_format variable into a double so this contains a comma which will break it. So either move the insert before or use a different variable name for the number formatted section. I have replicated this locally and it now works.

Comment: If you need an example here it is. Make sure you have your values in the correct order. $numberOfRows = 13300.1;
$total     = $numberOfRows * 3;

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO carbook (price, total_all) VALUES ('$total', '$numberOfRows')");
$total = number_format($total, 2);

echo 'Price per day: RM<b>' . $numberOfRows . '</b>.<br/>';
echo 'Total Price: RM<b>' . $total . '</b>.';

Comment: I've updated my answer with the formatting and the correct code that works

Comment: i will try that and i will update you later
thanks in advance mate , brilliant helping hand ever

Comment: emmm...the problem still persist, do i need to change something in the table to make it work? eg, type,name etc...

Comment: Shouldn’t have to. I created a table to match yours from the image and used the exact code I posted above.

Comment: it still fetching 0 somehow...do i have to free result from earlier query?

Comment: I am not sure. What you should do is remove the code I put in the edit into a simple PHP page and change the $count[‘NumRows’] to 13300 and then run it. If it works then it’s a problem in your code if not then something else. I have it working on my local with that EDIT I put in.

Comment: ive tried changing $numberofRows to 13000, its still the same...so its something else then...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/GURy3 Here is exactly what I am doing and its working. Create your self a basic page and just test that it isn't your DB first as shown in the images in the link. If this works and it saves then its your code else its your DB and you need to investigate into that.