# mysql query to get percentage of certain field in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table of expenses:

```
Expense(amount: Double, vendorId: Int, vendorType: Int)
```

I want to create a mysql query that will give me the percentage of each vendor type with certain vendor, like:

```
vendorId   vendorType percentOfExpencesOfThisType    totalExpenses
```

so lets say I have 4 expences:

```
Expense(amount: 30.0, vendorId: 3, vendorType: 1)
Expense(amount: 58.5, vendorId: 3, vendorType: 1)
Expense(amount: 47.0, vendorId: 3, vendorType: 7)
Expense(amount: 21.5, vendorId: 3, vendorType: 13)
```

so the table will look:

```
vendorId   vendorType percentOfExpencesOfThisType    totalExpenses
3               1                 50                       4
3               7                 25                       4
3               13                25                       4
```

how would I do that?
(unfortunately using mysql version 5.6)

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831217/double-vs-decimal-in-mysql

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you I will read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select vendorId, vendorType,
       100 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by vendorId) as percentOfExpensesOfThisType,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by vendorId) as totalExpenses
from expense
group by vendorId, vendorType;
```

Window functions are available starting in MySQL 8+.

In earlier versions, you would be joining two aggregation queries:

```
select vendorId, vendorType,
       100 * vt.cnt / v.cnt as percentOfExpensesOfThisType,
       v.cnt as totalExpenses
from (select vendorId, vendorType, count(*) as cnt
      from expense
      group by vendorId, vendorType
     ) vt join
     (select vendorId, count(*) as cnt
      from expense
      group by vendorId
     ) v
     on vt.vendorId = v.vendorId;
```

Comment: unfortunately using mysql version 5.6