# Mysql function adding unwanted decimals on addition

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a simple MySQL function for addition, the function works well for numbers with up to 10 decimal places, but when I pass A as 17.565714285714 and B as 22.8 I got 40.365714285714006 the function append 006 to the result, what could be a reason and how can I solve it.
Mysql version is 8.0.18

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
FUNCTION `addition`(`A` DOUBLE, `B` DOUBLE) 
RETURNS DOUBLE
NO SQL
BEGIN
 RETURN A + B;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831217/double-vs-decimal-in-mysql

Comment: Use DOUBLE datatype never when you need in precise value.

Comment: please prefer using text data rather than images.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan noted